# Skipping an errored for loop iteration VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an Excel Macro to lookup company names and return the ticker. As you can imagine, sometimes the database does not find a match for the company name. When this happens, I want it to go to the Catch: section of my code, and, after that, go on to the next cell. Is it possible to do this the way I have written my code?

```
Sub TickerLookup()
StartFunction:
    For Each c In Selection
         On Error GoTo Catch

         cell = c.Value
         remCo = Replace(cell, "CO", "")
         remCos = Replace(remCo, "COS", "")
         remNew = Replace(remCos, "NEW", "")
         cmpnyName = Replace(remNew, "INTL", "")
         ticker = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=" & cmpnyName

         Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
         MyRequest.Open "GET", ticker
         MyRequest.Send

         Dim Json As Object
         Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)

         'Set the cell to the left as ticker

         c.Offset(, -1).Value = Json(1)("Symbol")

    Next
Exit Sub

Catch:
         FirstName = Trim$(Left$(cell, InStr(cell, " ") - 1))
         MsgBox "Now trying: " & FirstName
         ticker2 = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=" & FirstName
         MyRequest.Open "GET", ticker2
         MyRequest.Send
         Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
         c.Offset(, -1).Value = Json(1)("Symbol")
         GoTo StartFunction
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like it would work fine. The only change I'd make is moving the `StartFunction:` below the `For each c in Selection` line. This way you don't start checking all the cells over again and instead pickup where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

Could you move the on error outside the **for each**? Then move the **next** into the catch handler?

Answer (score 0):

The following modification of your code places all handling inside the loop. It further moves the error catching to the part wehere you exepect the error (in your code every error was caught, even those you don't know how to handle, such as a malformed http request):

```
Sub TickerLookup()
    For Each c In Selection

         cell = c.Value
         remCo = Replace(cell, "CO", "")
         remCos = Replace(remCo, "COS", "")
         remNew = Replace(remCos, "NEW", "")
         cmpnyName = Replace(remNew, "INTL", "")
         ticker = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=" & cmpnyName

         Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
         MyRequest.Open "GET", ticker
         MyRequest.Send

         On Error GoTo Catch
         Dim Json As Object
             Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
         On Error GoTo 0

         'Set the cell to the left as ticker

         c.Offset(, -1).Value = Json(1)("Symbol")
         GoTo CatchContinue

Catch:
         On Error GoTo 0
         FirstName = Trim$(Left$(cell, InStr(cell, " ") - 1))
         MsgBox "Now trying: " & FirstName
         ticker2 = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=" & FirstName
         MyRequest.Open "GET", ticker2
         MyRequest.Send
         On error GoTo Catch2             
             Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
         c.Offset(, -1).Value = Json(1)("Symbol")
Catch2:
         On Error GoTo 0
CatchContinue:
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it errored out on cells it used to work on before. Your code doesn't seem to work on anything.

Comment: Thank you for your compiiment. If there are errors in cells it used to work on then that is entirely your problem & error. This code only handles errros due to Json parsing, as you requested. I wish you lots of fun in debugging.